# How to initialize a map of char to char with null values in c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures

I am trying to store the parent of each node in an unordered map and I need to initialize the values with NULL, like this:

```
//This is inside a method of a template class
std::unordered_map<T, T> parent;
parent[start] = NULL;
```

This throws a warning:

```
warning: converting to non-pointer type 'std::unordered_map<char, char, std::hash<char>, std::equal_to<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, char> > >::mapped_type' {aka 'char'} from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
      parent[start] = NULL;
```

This works when T is char but does not work with other types.

```
//This is inside a method of a template class
std::unordered_map<T, T> parent;
parent[start] = '\0';
```

How to make it such that I can store the value of the keys as NULL.
P.S: I am new to c++.

```
T curr = end; // Here end is variable passed by user
 while(curr != NULL) { // I want to check whether current is NULL
 res.push(curr); // res is a stack, and I push the element(value of key)to it
 curr = parent[curr];
}
```

I want to check for a NULL value and stop the while loop.

Here is the full code for the method:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<list>
#include<queue>
#include <climits>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class TemplateGraph {

  private:
    int V;
    unordered_map<T, list<pair<T, int>>> adjList;
    
  public:
    TemplateGraph(int v): V(v) {}
    void addEdge(T from, T to,bool isBiDir, int weight) {
      adjList[from].push_back(make_pair(to, weight));
      if(isBiDir) {
        adjList[to].push_back(make_pair(from, weight));
      }
    }
   void getPath(T start, T end) {
      unordered_map<T, int> dist;
      priority_queue<pair<T, int>, vector<pair<T, int>>, greater<pair<T, int>>> pq;
      unordered_map<T, T> parent;
      stack<T> res;
// adjList is of type =
// unordered_map<T, list<pair<T, int>>> adjList;
      for(auto vtx: adjList) { 
        T key = vtx.first;
        dist[key] = INT_MAX;
      }
      pq.push(make_pair(start, 0));
      dist[start] = 0;
      parent[start] = 0;
      while(!pq.empty()){
        T top = pq.top().first;
        pq.pop();
        for(auto nbr: adjList[top]){
          T node = nbr.first;
          int wt = nbr.second;
          int newWt = dist[top] + wt;
          if(newWt < dist[node]) {
            dist[node] = newWt;
            pq.push(make_pair(node, dist[node]));
            parent[node] = top;
          }
        }
      }
      T curr = end;
      while(curr != 0) {
        res.push(curr);
        curr = parent[curr];
      }
      while(!res.empty()){
        T node = res.top();
        res.pop();
        cout << node << " ";
      } 
    }
}

int main(){
  TemplateGraph<char> g2(9);
  g2.addEdge('A', 'B', true, 2);
  g2.addEdge('A', 'C', true, 5);
  g2.addEdge('B', 'D', true, 7);
  g2.addEdge('C', 'D', true, 2);
  g2.addEdge('C', 'E', true, 3);
  g2.addEdge('E', 'F', true, 4);
  g2.addEdge('E', 'H', true, 3);
  g2.addEdge('F', 'G', true, 1);
  g2.addEdge('D', 'F', true, 1);
  g2.getPath('A', 'F');
  TemplateGraph<int> g(9);
  g.addEdge(1, 2, true, 4);
  g.addEdge(4, 1, true, 3);
  g.addEdge(2, 3, true, 2);
  g.addEdge(2, 5, true, 4);
  g.addEdge(4, 5, true, 1);
  g.addEdge(3, 8, true, 5);
  g.addEdge(3, 7, true, 2);
  g.addEdge(7, 9, true, 1);
  g.getPath(1, 5);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char`s do not have null values. They can have the value zero though. What are you hoping for with `NULL`? "_How to make it such that I can store the value of the keys as NULL_" - It looks like you are setting the values to `NULL` - not the keys.

Comment: Do you just want to insert a "default-value" like `'\0'`, `nullptr`, `0`, `0.0` depending on `T`? Maybe you also want to do something where `std::optional` can help you. More code might help to clarify.

Comment: I want to initialize the first key as NULL and in a loop, I'll add the parent node for each node. I need NULL for the first key so that I can range check while traversing the nodes by following its parent. Kind of like we did in Dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: I would suggest a different tactic - don't try to put NULL values in the map at all. Only add keys that have actual values to assign. You can use the map's `find()` method to determine if a given key exists in the map, and get an iterator to it only if it does exist.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you!!! It's working fine now...

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't have the concept of "an empty value".  All integers have integer values, all chars have char values, and all strings have string values, and all pointers have pointer values. Always.  Now, it could be that you have a value that you *treat* like empty, such as `nullptr` for pointers and `'\0'` for chars and `0` for integers, but the variable still exists holds that as a value.

You can usually just use `{}` to get the default value for any type, and treat that as a magic "no value" if you wish. Alternatively, you can use [`std::optional<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), which can have the value of [`std::nullopt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt) in addition to any valid value of `T`.

Comment: "*C++ doesn't have the concept of "an empty value"*" - actually, it does, via [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Answer (score -1):

'\0' is of type char.
NULL is a macro of type void *

you can either use '\0' or you can store a char-pointer instead of char. for example char*

Comment: [From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL): "_In C, the macro `NULL` may have the type `void*`, but that is not allowed in C++_"

Comment: Thanks for responding, when T is char, '/0' works fine . But is does not work for int and string(as expected). I'm using template, so I need a solution that works fine for all of them, i.e, int, char and string. Is there any way to make the map such that it can accept both T and NULL?

Comment: I want to initialize the first key as NULL and in a loop, I'll add the parent node for each node. I need NULL for the first key so that I can range check while traversing the nodes by following its parent. Kind of like we did in Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Then how can I initialize a variable with an empty value? Is there any way? I am coming from JS background.